# Link two workflows (or break a very long workflow into sections)

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I just started working with Sharepoint and have no background whatsoever with the application. I also don't have any experience in programming. My boss gave me a task of putting our orientation check list into Sharepoint that whenever there's a new employee, they'll just click a button on that employee's page and generate these orientation tasks (like read manuals, shadow train with existing staff, make mock calls, etc.).

I managed to make it but the tasks is so long that it's quite a bit overwhelming for the new employee. I broke the tasks into 2 workflow but can't seem to figure out how to connect these 2. I read that you can't call a Sharepoint workflow 2013 from a Sharepoint workflow 2013 without a workaround.

What do you reckon is the best approach in doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a pause line within the workflow if you're wanting to slowly add more tasks. That could ease up the bulk task assignment.

Are you wanting to make it easier for you to write the workflow or are you wanting to ease the new employee into their tasks?

Comment: I want to ease the new employee into their tasks. I'll look into that pause suggestion of yours. Thanks!